# Laravel - Composer update and hosting on azure issue

Tags: laravel, azure, laravel-5, composer-php

I was developing my project locally on my computer and pushing updates to Azure using Git, the issue now I am facing is that I have ran `Composer update` command locally and now I have pushed my current updates to azure I am getting this error

```
 Problem 1
 remote:     - Installation request for doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 -> satisfiable by 
 doctrine/inflector[v1.3.0].
 remote:     - doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.32) 
 does not satisfy that requirement.
 remote:   Problem 2
 remote:     - Installation request for symfony/contracts v1.0.2 -> satisfiable by 
 symfony/contracts[v1.0.2].
 remote:     - symfony/contracts v1.0.2 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version 
 (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
 remote:   Problem 3
 remote:     - Installation request for symfony/css-selector v4.2.1 -> satisfiable by 
 symfony/css-selector[v4.2.1].
 remote:     - symfony/css-selector v4.2.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version 
 (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
 remote:   Problem 4
 remote:     - Installation request for symfony/event-dispatcher v4.2.1 -> satisfiable 
 by symfony/event-dispatcher[v4.2.1].
 remote:     - symfony/event-dispatcher v4.2.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version 
 (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
 remote:   Problem 5
 remote:     - Installation request for symfony/translation v4.2.1 -> satisfiable by 
 symfony/translation[v4.2.1].
 remote:     - symfony/translation v4.2.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version 
 (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
 remote:   Problem 6
 remote:     - symfony/translation v4.2.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version 
 (7.0.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
 remote:     - nesbot/carbon 1.36.2 requires symfony/translation ~2.6 || ~3.0 || ~4.0 - 
 > satisfiable by symfony/translation[v4.2.1].
 remote:     - Installation request for nesbot/carbon 1.36.2 -> satisfiable by 
 nesbot/carbon[1.36.2].
 remote:
 remote:
 remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website 
 failed.
 To https://#####.azurewebsites.net/#####.git
  + da3acfe...3dfc921 master -> master (forced update)
```

Comment: which version of your laravel project ?

Comment: laravel version is 5.4.36

Comment: Some of the packages in your `composer.lock` file require PHP 7.1. PHP 7.0 is unsupported as of 30 days ago, you shouldn't still be using it anyways: http://php.net/eol.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to require `PHP 7.1.3` your PHP version (7.0.32) does not satisfy some package that requirement.

Apart from this, PHP 7.0 is [unsupported](http://php.net/eol.php) since December 3, 2018.

Answer (score 0):

You have just updated all of your composer packages to which they are no longer supported by PHP 7.0, you will need to upgrade your PHP version to at least `7.1.3` however I recommend updating to the latest stable which is currently `7.3.0`.

There are lots of solutions out there on how to upgrade your PHP version but [here is one I found](https://jakelprice.com/article/how-to-upgrade-from-php-70-to-php-71), or read below.

**Run to make sure you have  the PHP repository.**

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
$ sudo apt-get update
```

**Stop Your Server && Install PHP 7.1**

```
$ service apache2 stop 
**// OR depending on what you use.**
$ service nginx stop

$ sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-common
```

**Laravel and Composer specifics**

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl php7.1-xml php7.1-zip php7.1-gd php7.1-mysql php7.1-mbstring
```

**Check your version**

```
$ php -v
```

It should read 7.1

**Remove 7.0**

```
$ sudo apt-get purge php7.0 php7.0-common
```

**Showdown/Restart the server**

```
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

**If you're using apache, tell apache to use 7.1**

```
$ a2enmod php7.1
$ service apache2 restart
```

This should be enough to get you running, but ideally you would update to the latest stable. Just make sure you keep everything updated moving forward.